# Definition of Unit Test method which calls stored procedure to retrieve data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have following method in asp.net code behind page which calls stored procedure and return results. I am not sure about definition of unit test method i am supposed to write to test this method.

```
public List<BlogDetail> GetData()
    {
        List<BlogDetail> allBlogDetail = new List<BlogDetail>();

        using (var db = new BloggingContext("CodeFirstSampleConnectionString")) //name=CodeFirstSample
        {
            allBlogDetail = db.Database.SqlQuery<BlogDetail>("uspGetAllBlogs").ToList();
        }

        return allBlogDetail;
    }
```

Following is the unit test method i wrote to test this method. As far as i know, it is not a good practice to make database calls in unit test which i have violated by making a database call in unit test method.

```
public void GetDataTest()
    {
        Default target = new Default();
        List<BlogDetail> expected = new List<BlogDetail>();
        List<BlogDetail> actual = new List<BlogDetail>();

        using (var db = new BloggingContext("DemoConnectionString")) 
        {
            expected = db.Database.SqlQuery<BlogDetail>("uspGetAllBlogs").ToList();
        }

        actual = target.GetData();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, actual.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[i].BlogID, actual[i].BlogID);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[i].BlogName, actual[i].BlogName);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[i].PostID, actual[i].PostID);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[i].PostTitle, actual[i].PostTitle);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[i].PostContent, actual[i].PostContent);
        }
    }
```

I have read that unit test should be repeatable and predictable and by writing above method i have violated both the rules.

This unit test takes at at least 30 seconds to run in a local database and apparently it will take more time when tested with remote database.

Result of stored procedure is also not predictable as stored procedure can return variable records when called at different times. Since database is fed with data at regular interval.

I have no idea about definition of unit test method. Is my unit test method correct? Do i need to take different approach? Please help.

Comment: What are you testing exactly? The stored procedure itself? The mapping to C# objects? To write a unit test you should know what you want to test

Comment: This is really part of a much bigger discussion. But in my opinion I would not be testing the content of what is returned but more of the structure. To ensure that the DB has not changed whereby I can no longer construct my objects... UPDATE: I just realised the tag of `entity-framework` in which case I think this test is pretty redundant, in my opinion

Comment: @margabit i can understand the description may not to the point as what i am asking but it is the same question that you have written. Am i supposed to write i am a newbie to unit testing etc etc in a description to make you believe that my questions is fair enough. This is the point i do not understand, what i am supposed to unit test in this method? and yes, i have just started with unit testing and quite a newbie and don't understand much concepts and i need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to test whether the `GetData()` method calls the `uspGetAllBlogs` SP. In your current code, this is impossible, as the `GetData()` method does too much.

A repository pattern may help here, when the repository is injected into your `Default`:

```
interface IBlogRepository
{
    List<BlogDetail> GetAllBlogs();
}

class BlogRepository : IBlogRepository
{
    public List<BlogDetail> GetAllBlogs()
    {
        using (var db = new BloggingContext("CodeFirstSampleConnectionString"))
        {
            return db.Database.SqlQuery<BlogDetail>("uspGetAllBlogs").ToList();
        }
    }
}

class Default
{
    private readonly IBlogRepository _blogRepository;

    public Default(IBlogRepository blogRepository)
    {
        _blogRepository = blogRepository;
    }

    public List<BlogDetail> GetData()
    {
        return _blogRepository.GetAllBlogs();
    }
}
```

Now you can mock your repository when testing, and you only have to verify *that* your repository's `GetAllBlogs()` method is called, not *what* it returns:

```
public void GetDataTest()
{
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IBlogRepository>();
    mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetAllBlogs()).Returns(new List<BlogDetail>());
    Default target = new Default(mockRepository.Object);

    var actual = target.GetData();

    Assert.AreEqual(0, actual.Count);       
    mockRepository.Verify(r => r.GetAllBlogs(), Times.Once());
}
```

After this you'll be wanting to unit test your `BlogRepository`. In order to do that, you'll have to interface your `BloggingContext` and verify the `Database.SqlQuery()` method is called with the proper parameters, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand all the code you have provided but i still have a question. What will i be testing while testing BlogRepository?

Comment: @nccsbim071 you'll only be testing whether your repository calls a stored procedure named `uspGetAllBlogs`. You don't have to verify that Entity Framework actually connects to the database, executes the stored procedure and materializes the resultset into an `IQueryable<T>`, because that part is Entity Framework's responsibility: they have test code for that. You can assume it does what it promises. (Although there are different schools of thought on that, just search the web for "entity framework unit testing".)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question would be so long... Try reading about separation of your UI (asp.net page and its code behind) and your application logic. Take a peek at dependency injection maybe. What you simply need to do is to inject `Repository` pattern or something like it to your class and make it get the data. That way you can inject mockup implementation of your repository object that will return predefined data.